# Issue returning data using SQL when matching on nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with a table which has been provided to me:

**INP_PRODUCTS**

- INP_ID
- INP_PRODUCT_NAME
- INP_PRODUCT_DESC
- INP_PRODUCT_CODE
- INP_PRODUCT_TYPE

So the INP_PRODUCT_CODE and and INP_PRODUCT_TYPE columns values can be null. I am trying to construct a query where if the end user provides the value of "UNKNOWN" regarding the ProductCode then i would like to *match on the null* value of that column. The user is providing multiple ProductCodes as the input paramater.

Secondly if the user provides a list of ProductTypes and one of the value is "UNKNOWN" then I would like to *match on the null value* for that column.

Below is the SQL i have constructed but the results are not showing as expected. I know this query is not correct. I appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction:

```
SELECT INP_PRODUCT_ID, NVL(INP_PRODUCT_CODE, 'UNKNOWN'),   NVL(INP_PRODUCT_TYPE, 'UNKNOWN')
from INP_PRODUCTS where INP_PRODUCT_CODE IN('ABC', 'UNKNOWN', 'UUU') and INP_PRODUCT_TYPE in('CONSOLE','UNKNOWN','KITCHENAPPLIANCE')
```

I appreciate constructive input please on the above.

Kind Regards,

**UPDATE regarding the above!**

I got it to work by modifying my query specifically my where clause:

```
SELECT COALESCE(INP_PRODUCT_CODE,'UNKNOWN') as INP_PRODUCT_CODE,
COALESCE(INP_PRODUCT_TYPE, 'UNKNOWN') as INP_PRODUCT_TYPE
FROM INP_PRODUCTS
WHERE COALESCE(INP_PRODUCT_CODE,'UNKNOWN')
IN ('ABC','UNKNOWN', 'UUU') AND COALESCE(INP_PRODUCT_TYPE, 'UNKNOWN') IN('CONSOLE','UNKNOWN','KITCHENAPPLIANCE');
```

If you think my above query is not quite right then please respond to my question and provide me feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change its value to 'UNKNOWN' only or to have the tuple also returned?

Comment: You may have meant `WHERE (COALESCE(INP_PRODUCT_CODE,'UNKNOWN'),COALESCE(INP_PRODUCT_TYPE, 'UNKNOWN')) IN (('ABC','CONSOLE'),('UNKNOWN','UNKNOWN'),('UUU','KITCHENAPPLIANCE'))`

Answer (score 0):

The COALESCE clause returns the first non_null expression from the expression list.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm

If you have only 1 column te check if it is null or not, then use the NVL statement. Use COALESCE if you want to check more columns is they are null of not.

```
SELECT nvl(INP_PRODUCT_CODE,'UNKNOWN') as INP_PRODUCT_CODE,
       nvl(INP_PRODUCT_TYPE, 'UNKNOWN') as INP_PRODUCT_TYPE
FROM INP_PRODUCTS
WHERE nvl(INP_PRODUCT_CODE,'UNKNOWN')IN ('ABC','UNKNOWN', 'UUU') ---> if you also want de prod-codes ABC and UUU
AND   nvl(INP_PRODUCT_TYPE, 'UNKNOWN') IN ('CONSOLE','UNKNOWN','KITCHENAPPLIANCE');  ---> if you also want the types console and kitchenappliance
```